# Not able to mock jdbcTemplate in Spring boot Test class

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring boot and Mockito for testing. I have been able to write test cases for Service layer and they re working fine. But, the test cases for DAO layer do not. The `jdbcTemplate` object that is mocked and autowired gives `null` pointer when executing the test case. Below are the details:

My `DAOTest` class:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = EcommerceApplication.class)
public classEcommerceDaoTest {

@InjectMocks
private IEcommerceDao ecommerceDao = new EcommerceDaoImpl();

@Mock
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate as400JdbcTemplate;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

}

@Test
public void checkOrderExistsTest() throws EcommerceException{
    Mockito.when(as400JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryForOrder,new Object[]
{"1000"}, int.class)).thenReturn(1);
    boolean exists = 
 ecommerceDao.checkOrderExists("1000");
    assertTrue(exists);
}
}
```

EcommerceDAOImpl.java:

```java
@Override
public boolean checkOrderExists(String orderNo)throws EcommerceException{
boolean doesExist = false;
    int count = 0;
    try{
        count= as400JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(queryForOrder, new Object[]{orderNo}, int.class);
if(count >0){
doesExist = true;
}
    }
catch(Exception e){
}
return doesExist;
}
```

AS400Config.java:

```java
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate as400JdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("as400DataSource")DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

ECommerceApplication.java

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import(As400Configuration.class)
public class EcommerceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EcommerceApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

When I am running the test case, I am getting `NullPointerException` for `as400JdbcTemplate`. The functionality works fine as is. Its just the test cases for DAO layer that fail because of the inability of the `jdbcTemplate` to get mocked/autowired.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `@Mock` and `@Autowired` at the same time. Use only `@Mock`:

   `@Mock
   private JdbcTemplate as400JdbcTemplate;`
2. Use instead of  `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` --> `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Also to inject mock into DAO you can use [ReflectionTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) from spring test.

> public static void setField(Class targetClass, String name, Object value)

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ecommerceDao ,"as400JdbcTemplate" , 
      as400JdbcTemplate);

}

@Mock
    private JdbcTemplate as400JdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working now. I just added the MockitoJUnitRunner.class. But I have an additional query here. One of the methods in my dao is using a RowMapper class (to populate result set data in an object)that I have in the same java file as my DAOImpl. So,the public class is the daoimpl and that other class which is implementing RowMapper is also there in the same file.(It is not an inner class). So, when I am testing this method, it is failing.

Comment: I am using : `Mockito.when(as400JdbcTemplate.query(queryForShipment, new Object[]{"1000"}, new ShipmentRowMapper())).thenReturn(updates);` And in the main dao method: `list =  as400JdbcTemplate.query(queryForShipment,new Object[]{orderNo},new ShipmentRowMapper());` The list is null on testing.

Comment: I modified the code from:list = `as400JdbcTemplate.query(queryForShipment,new Object[]{orderNo},new ShipmentRowMapper());` to : `list = as400JdbcTemplate.query(queryForShipment,new Object[]{orderNo},shipmentRowMapper);` and defined at the class level `shipmentRowMapper = new ShipmentRowMapper();` and its working now.

Comment: Yes, i just did.Thanks.